# Is it possible to use a keyboard and mouse on android to control a remote pc?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, remote-access

There are apps like TeamViewer where you can control a pc remotely, my question is if it's possible to use mouse and keyboard otg on the android device to actually control the desktop pc?, like if you were in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Splashtop (another remote desktop app, just like TeamViewer), and mouse & keyboard works just fine, but definitely not exactly like you're "in front of it". It can recognize right clicks (Android can't natively), but lots of common shortcut keys like Alt+Tab or Win+* are absent, not necessarily because the software can't support it, but because they already have a purpose in Android itself and that's of higher priority. For example, Alt+Tab actually switches apps on the Android device, instead of the remote one.

Comment: If there's anything (mouse operation, keyboard shortcut) you need to test out, try Splashtop for free in LAN environment first, because remote across network is a paid feature.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it when I get home, will mark this as accepted answer once I test it

Comment: Tested it, my android only displayed black screen even with compatible mode, but the mouse indeed controlled the pc. So that is a solution, but didnt work for me.

Comment: @KillerPollo Weird. Splashtop has been my god to solution and has worked for me since Android 4.4 on various devices. At least I got your question answered...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external keyboard and external mouse in teamviewer, you can right click, left click but can't alt+tab, it switches Android apps to another Android app.